# C++ determine the type of auto and pass to function template

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have a function :

```
template<typename T> f(T x) { do something with x; }
```

I want to pass this auto pointer into the function

```
auto x = ...
f<???>(x)
```

Is there anyway for me to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call it like

```
auto x = ...
f(x)
```

templated functions automatically deduce the type depending on the arguments you pass it. In fact that's the preferred way to call a templated function.

If you really want to explicitly give it the type (I don't recommend doing that) you can use decltype for it:

```
auto x = ...
f<decltype(x)>(x)
```

---

Here a minimal proof: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d01070d90c0b9803

Answer (score 3):

compiler should be smart enough to figure out the type, so

```
auto x = ...
f(x);
```

or you can use `decltype`

```
auto x = ...
f<decltype(x)>(x);
```

Comment: decltype is what I need!! somehow in my case compiler does not determine the type.. Now who should I accept the answer...

Comment: @w00d Raphael and me have almost the same answer and at same time... so just accept anyone... you can still upvote the other one or both if you like.